# how to plot ohlc candlestick using pandas dataframe and matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x

I just used pandas dataframe & matplotlib to draw the intraday ohlc +volume.
But the x-ticks in ax1 and ax2 seems not matched with each other.

This is the graph that doesn't share-axis:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIngm.jpg

If I use sharex = ax1, the chart becomes:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq4vQ.jpg

And the coding is

```
column_names = ['stockName','contract','unixStamp', 'dateStamp', 'excPrice', 'excVolume']
df = pd.read_csv(file,header=None, names = column_names)
df['Time']=pd.to_datetime(df.dateStamp)
df.set_index('Time',inplace = True)

df_ohlc = df['excPrice'].resample('1T').ohlc()
df_vol = df['excVolume'].resample('1T').sum()
df_full = pd.concat([df_ohlc, df_vol], axis=1)

#df_ohlc.insert(0, 'time' , df_ohlc.index)
print(df_full.head())

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((5,4),(0,0),rowspan=4, colspan=4)
##ax1.axes.set_xticks(df_ohlc['time'])
candlestick2_ohlc(ax1, df_ohlc['open'], df_ohlc['high'],df_ohlc['low'],df_ohlc['close'],width=1, colorup='r', colordown='g')

ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((5,4),(4,0), sharex= ax1, rowspan=1, colspan=4)
ax2.plot(df_full.index, df_full['excVolume'] , '#00ffe8')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

How can I fix the chart to co-ordinate the x-axis?
Thanks!